# how to draw hue component of an image

Tags: image-processing, hsl

I extracted the hue component of an image and I need to render it. Hue is angular value ranges [0° - 360°] and it isn't reasonable to normalize it to [0 - 255] using min-max normalization as follows:
value = (hue - 0) * 255 / (360 - 0)

Any idea how to normalize the hue values to [0 - 255]?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to normalise from one range to another given the input range [inp_min - inp_max] and output range [out_min - out_max] is to use
out = (inp - inp_min) / (inp_max - inp_min) * (out_max - out_min) + out_min

So, use:
value = (hue-0) / (360-0) * (255-0) + 0

Or more simply:
value = hue * 255 / 360

EDIT

So from the comments below, I now understand the question.  What is really being asked is how to translate a hue value to an RGB triplet.  Using the [wikipedia page on HSL/HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) as a reference:

h' = hue/60

x = (1 - |(h' mod 2) - 1|) * 255

if (h'<=1) RGB = (255, x, 0)

else if (h'<=2) RGB = (x, 255, 0)

else if (h'<=3) RGB = (0, 255, x)

else if (h'<=4) RGB = (0, x, 255)

else if (h'<=5) RGB = (x, 0, 255)

else RGB = (255, 0, x)

This is, in essence, the HSL calculation with S = 100%, L=50%

Of course the simplest way, if you do not need to do the calculation yourself, is just to use something like [this website](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hsl-to-rgb.html).

Comment: That is wrong. In this way you assign 360° the intensity value 255 and 0° to the intensity value 0. While 360° and 0° are identical..

Comment: I see your point, so actually you want [0-360] to map to [0-256] where 0===360 and 0===256.

Comment: How about (hue*256/360) mod 256

Comment: No, 0 not equal to 255. It express the intensity. While hue is angular

Comment: Also wrong, because 350° - 358° will have a high intensity values and 2° - 10° a low intensity values

Comment: Then I am really not clear about your question.  Are you wanting to map hue to a 0-255 range (where an 8-bit value logically wraps 256 becoming 0) or it some other value (the L of HLS perhaps) you are wanting to map somehow?

Comment: You can't map a hue to intensity.  There is a standard mapping of HSL values to 8-bit values and you can then map all three to a 0-255 range, this does not mean that hue is then represented as an intensity, just that you are using the fact that an 8-bit value wraps around at 256 in the same way that an angle wraps at 360

Comment: I extracted hue component and I only want to see the result on my screen. To do that I have to convert the hue component in somehow to rgb so I can then render it.

Comment: For example when you convert your image to CMYK  and you need to display the Y component basically you assign it to r, g, and b (r = g = b = Y)
because both of them are ranging from 0 - 255 and they are NOT angular

If you want to display B component of LAB, you need to map it first from [-500 500] to [0 255] using the minmax approach which you have explained on your very beginning answer

Comment: I think you are getting confused.  The Y in CMYK is for Yellow.  Not the same as the Y in the CIE XYZ (which is just luminance).  To convert from CMYK (for example) to RGB you need to take into account ALL of the values.  You also need to account, potentially, for the gamma being used (I am assuming that since CMYK is a print specification it is linear.  RGB is based on the sRGB specification and that assumes a power law response).  Mapping between these colour spaces (and especially things like CIELab) is complex and very nonlinear.

Comment: This is one of the definitions of hue, I've seen others too. :)

Comment: And my mistake that it is not possible to map hue to intensity because the space dimension of hue is bigger than that of intensity. In your solution, you overcome this point by mapping to 360 colors. Good job :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you started off with RGB, and converted to HSV to get the H value.

The easiest way to display this H value is assign a large value to S (max saturation), and a medium value to V (not max intensity, as that leads to white), and apply the inverse transform (HSV to RGB). This yields an RGB image with a color representation for H.

By using the inverse transform (which I assume comes in the same library you used for the RGB to HSV transform), you make sure that the same definition of H is used. I have seen many different definitions of HSV (and HSI, HSL, ISH, etc, etc) -- everybody uses their own it seems.